# Grails 3 - Read classpath resource in Bootstrap.groovy

Tags: grails, grails-3.0, grails-3.0.9

I'm migrating a Grails 2.5 application to Grails `3.0.9` and having some issue reading a classpath resource in `grails-app/init/BootStrap.groovy`.

In Grails 2.5.x it was possible to access resource (e.g. textfiles) using the Spring `ClassPathResource` when putting the resource file into the same folder as the `BootStrap.groovy`

```
def file1 = new ClassPathResource('my-textfile.txt').file
```

In Grails 3 it works when I start my application using `grails run-app`. All resources are taken from `src/main/resources`. But if I start the application using the Spring Boot Application (located at `/grails-app/init/a/b/Application.groovy`) class in IntelliJ the BootStrap.groovy find the resources anymore.

Does anyone know how to access these files within `BootStrap.groovy` in Grails 3.0.9 when starting the app using `Application.groovy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Gradle convention I place the resources under `src/main/resource` since they need to be accessible at runtime.

For some reasons my `grails-app/init/a/b/Application.groovy` can't find these resources so I had to place a symbolic link to `grails-app/init/a/b`. After that everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
class BootStrap {

     def init = { servletContext ->

        def config = new ConfigSlurper().parse(new File("${System.properties['user.dir']}/grails-app/conf/test.groovy").toURL())
        println config
        println config.hfy.test
    }
    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

${System.properties['user.dir']}  :  Project directory